# ( VUE Computed ) Property 'XXX' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance'

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I using Vue 3 typescript and I've tried to create a computed property `classes` and contain return object like these

**NavbarTypes.ts**

```
interface INavbar {
  onScroll?: boolean,
  navbarActive?: boolean
}

export default INavbar
```

---

```
data (): NavbarTypes {
  return {
    onScroll: false,
    navbarActive: false,
  }
}

computed: {
  classes () {
    return {
      "navbar--on-scroll": this.onScroll,
      "navbar--active": this.navbarActive
    }
  }
}
```

but I got these error

```
(property) onScroll?: boolean | undefined

Property 'onScroll' does not exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, EmitsOptions, {}, {}, false, OptionTypesType<{}, ... 4 more ..., {}>, ... 5 more ..., {}>'.
```

I think this is because of the return type on the computed. But I'm not so sure and I don't know how to make the return type object

Hope you all can help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using vue 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim I'm sorry,, I'm using vue 3

Comment: please share the whole component code

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Here https://codepen.io/bukandicki/pen/vYxjvgX?editors=1010

Comment: Did you try removing the `?` which makes the `onScroll` property optional?

Comment: @bkndvlpr where are you getting the error? In vue template? or where?

Answer (score 5):

computed property classes should declare a type, like this

```
computed: {
  classes ():any {
    return {
      "navbar--on-scroll": this.onScroll,
      "navbar--active": this.navbarActive
    }
  }
}
```